# RedirectToAction not working in Edge but working in all other browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, microsoft-edge

I am redirecting to another action using `RedirectToAction(actionName,RouteValue)`, but its not working in Microsoft Edge, though its working as expected in all other browsers.

Controller has an Authorize attribute but I have added AllowAnonymous in both of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the following code to use RedirectToAction(actionName, RouteValue) method, it works well on Asp.net MVC and Asp.net core application in Edge browser (44 version).

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Contact",new { id="1001" , name="AAA"});
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Contact(string id, string name)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

If still not working, do you meet any error? What's the Edge browser version you are using? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use **RedirectToActionPermanent** method? Maybe it can be a solution.

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Contact",new { id="1001" , name="AAA"});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoactionpermanent?view=aspnetcore-2.2